# Uso de props en reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo react con documentación oficial, allí en el tutorial de la pagina oficial desarrollan un pequeño ejemplo de el juego tic tac toe y lo entiendo pero hay una linea que me causa muchísima confusión. En el componente de ***square*** (que representa un cuadro del tablero de juego ) se recibe por parámetro un valor para rellenarlo mediante el **props**, que se envía desde el padre ***board***.

Mi confusión es en `square` es un botón que hace uso del evento *onClick*  este es el código:

```
function Square(props) {
return (
  <button
    className="square"
     onClick={ props.onClick} >
    {props.value}
  </button>
);`}`
```

Que significa esto `onClick={props.onClick}`? que función llama? o cual es la función del **props.onClick**?

Comment: mejora la redacción del título de tu pregunta, así como lo colocas no hace sentido en lo absoluto; te invito a leer [ask] y de paso haz el [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el onClick es un evento sintético de react. Cuando le pasas el manejador del evento (la función de que se ejecuta al hacer click)

```
<button
 className="square"
 onClick={ props.onClick} 
>
 {props.value}
</button>
```

Le estas pasando la referencia de la función onClick que le pasa desde el componente padre, funciona exactamente igual como un callback.

Esto es gracias a que en javascript literalmente puedes guardar una función en una variable o constante.

Para ejecutarla en otro ámbito o scope diferente el que fue declarada.

En este caso estas almacenado en el objeto de las propiedades del compon
ente Square la función llamada onClick que se declara en su componente padre para cuando se active el evento onClick del Square se ejecute en ese preciso instante.

Ejemplo:

```
Class ComponentePadre extends Component {
  constructor(...props){
    super(...props);
    this.onClick = this.onCLick.bind(this);
  }

  //manajador onClick que se pasas como props
  onCLick(e){ 
    console.log(e)
  }
  render(){
    return(
    //almacenado la funcion en el componente hijo para ser ejecutada  dentro de el.
     <ComponenteHijo onClick={this.onClick}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`props` es una variable que guarda los parámetros recibidos en a través de la etiqueta:

```
<Square onClick={funcionQueTrataElClick} value="valor">
```

Cuando generas ese `<square>` en el HTMLfinal , se sustituye por el código que devuelves, algo similar a:

```
<button className="square" onclick="funcionQueTrataElClick" value="valor">
```

Comment: que quiere decir  con que se sustituye por el codigo que devuelve ? porque eso es lo que me confunde en square no hay funcion para el click solo existe el render() , el evento para click esta en el padre Board  que maneja los state del padre :S

Comment: Si te fijas al momento de crear el Square (en el método _renderSquare_) se le manda el `onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}`, como dice Pablo esto es almacenado en las "props" de Square que recibí en su etiqueta `onClick`, luego puedes usar estas "props" en tu _class_ para diferentes cosas, en este caso crea un botón sentándole el función `onClick` que recibió